# Conditionally adding arguments to a constructor (C++)

Tags: c++, boost-process

Is there a way to conditionally add arguments to a constructor?  I'd also like to know what this type of construction is called so I can search it myself.

I'm creating a [`boost::process::child`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/process/reference.html#header.boost.process.args_hpp) using a constructor where I can pass any properties and things are mostly working great:

```
    m_proc = new boost::process::child(
        m_context,
        boost::process::exe       = m_config.exe,
        boost::process::args      = m_config.args,
        boost::process::env       = m_config.Environment,
        boost::process::start_dir = m_config.WorkingDirectory,
        boost::process::std_out   > m_stdout_pipe,
        boost::process::std_err   > m_stderr_pipe,
        boost::process::on_exit   = [this](int i, auto e){OnProcExit(i, e);},
        boost::process::extend::on_setup   = [this](auto&){OnProcSetup();},
        boost::process::extend::on_success = [this](auto&){OnProcSuccess();},
        boost::process::extend::on_error   = [this](auto&, auto ec){OnProcError(ec);}
    );
```

UNTIL I call `ls` with no arguments.  Then it returns

```
/usr/bin/ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
Process Exited (code:2)
```

If `m_config.args` is empty, I want to avoid passing it.  I tried:

```
    m_proc = new boost::process::child(
        ...
        boost::process::exe       = m_config.exe,
        m_config.args.empty() ? (void) : (boost::process::args = m_config.args),
        ...
    );
```

but that gives:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
```

I tried:

```
    m_proc = new boost::process::child(
        ...
        boost::process::exe       = m_config.exe,
        boost::process::args      = m_config.args.empty() ? {} : m_config.args,
        ...
```

But that gives:

```
initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator ?
error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
```

I understand that for this particular case, I could combine `exe` and `args` to make a `cmd`, but I'd also like to conditionally add other arguments like `boost::process::shell` or `boost::process::stdin`.

If I need to call different constructor code for every set of options, I would need to write N! calls to constructors where N is the number of options and that grows fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly.

C++ isn't python, there isn't any named parameters in C++, so this solution makes use of global variables (`boost::process::args`) which are fundamentally not thread safe and prone to usage errors as you experienced.

In the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/process/args.html) they state you don't need to use the global vars, so you can directly use the your `config` members here:

```
m_proc = new boost::process::child(
        m_context,
        m_config.exe,
        m_config.args,
        m_config.Environment,
[...]
```

By the way, the error you're reporting isn't due to a bad empty list passing (you can have `m_config.args = {}`) but probably to a wrong command argument list creation (if the list is empty, the `boost::process::child` code should create an non-empty string for the process's argument list, containing the executable name as the first argument).

The error you are reporting:

```
/usr/bin/ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
```

is likely due to the wrong argument list being generated by boost and it's not due to your (empty) `args` array.

So I would put a debug breakpoint on the Popen syscall here and walk backward until I figure out what went wrong in building the argument string.

Using a global variable like a parameter here is syntax candy, but it means operator overloading to an *unspecified* object (as stated in the documentation), so you actually don't know what's going on here (`a = b` when `a` is unknown can be anything in C++, like a crazy making `b` set to the value of `a` as in `T& operator =(T & b) { b = *this; return *this; }`). You'll need to debug what's going on here to figure out what is happening. As a short advice, try to avoid using *undefined* object if it's not required and unclear, and stick to usual C++ practices.